# Pouring technique for drip/pour over coffee

Tags: brewing-process, drip-brew, pour-over

I would like to know how to make decent coffee using a drip (pour over) coffee.

The kit I bought was from Japan and I observe in espresso shops they tend to use a thin spout (or gooseneck) water kettle to control the rate of delivery of water.

What else is important here aside from the fineness of the ground coffee?

Are there a recommended set of steps?

Should I pour from the middle outwards or edge towards the centre?

Should I 'wet' the coffee first?

Is there a recommended pouring time to perform all of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I highly recommend anyone looking at a pour over to take a look at the [Clever Dripper.](https://www.sweetmarias.com/clevercoffeedripperpictorial.php)  It's a pour over brewer with a plate at the bottom that restricts flow unless the unit is resting on a cup.  You can use it as a regular pour over or you can use it off a cup to steep your coffee.  It allows all the control of a press and the grounds free cup of a paper filter.

To answer your question, it depends on how you like your coffee.  Grind finer and/or pour slower and you will get a stronger cup of coffee.  Grind courser and pour more quickly and you will get a weaker cup of coffee.  Pouring from the center sometime results in a raised edge around the rim, which isn't ideal when I am trying to fill the cone as full as possible, but in a true pour over, may be fine.  Pouring from the side seems to sometimes result in a small island of dry grounds floating in the middle of the cone.  For that reason, I generally vary my pour around the cone to minimize either effect and then stir some for good measure.

Comment: Pour over coffee from coffee shops consistently taste much better than Clever or pour over coffee in my home even with same bean from same shop. I always wonder why.

Answer (score 6):

From this [site](http://www.seriouseats.com/2014/06/make-better-pourover-coffee-how-pourover-works-temperature-timing.html):

> 1. Start with a grind size around that of coarse sugar. (Think Sugar in the Raw.)
>
> How much: Most pourover drippers work best when they're between one
>   half to two-thirds full of coffee grounds. Any less than that, and
>   there won't be enough coffee to restrict the flow. Any more, and your
>   dripper may overflow. You'll also want to make sure you're dripping
>   into a large enough vessel. If you're the more precise-measurement
>   type, a good coffee-to-water ratio is between 60-70 grams of coffee
>   per liter of water (a mass ratio between 1:16 and 1:14.)
>
> 2. Get your clean (filtered if you need it) brew water ready. You'll be using water that's about 30 seconds off boil if you're pouring
>      straight out of your boiling kettle, or immediately off boil if you're
>      pouring into a second pouring kettle. I like about 207°F for medium to
>      light roasts, and about 10° lower for dark roasts.
> 3. Start your clock and add enough water to soak all of the coffee (a little premature dripping is okay). Wait for the coffee bed to stop
>      the initial swelling (about 30 seconds) before adding more water.
> 4. Continue your brew. Try to pour quickly, gently, and evenly across the surface of the coffee, pausing between pours to pace your brew to
>      your target brew time (see below). The distance that your brew water
>      drops can affect brew temperatures, as well as increase or decrease
>      the amount of agitation that the falling water creates wherever it
>      falls in the coffee bed. In general, the lower you pour from, the
>      better, if for no other reason than it's the easiest to create and
>      maintain consistency.
>
> When you stop adding water, your dripper will continue to drip for
>   between 20 and 60 seconds.
>
> Your target total brew time is about 2.5 to 3 minutes for dark roasted
>   coffee, and 3 to 4 minutes for medium to light roasted coffees. This
>   includes the dripping time after you stop adding water.

Comment: did you immediately answer your own question?

Comment: @JustinC yes the idea here is that this question I think will be useful for others, I was hoping for more answers which if better than my copy and paste effort I will accept

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what the citation standards for this site or if a "hey this worked for me, why don't you try it applies" so please downvote accordingly and point me to the correct meta articles.

But, what I've done, ever since I started making pour over coffee after watching Alton Brown extol it's virtues on Good Eats, is to use a tea pot with the lid closed and just pour slowly through the whistle-hole.

It kind of skunkifies the tea pot if you've got sort of hard water (even happens to me with reverse-osmosis water), but it hasn't ruined the whistle-hole of the teapot and it does a good job to control the flow and it's cheap and a multi-purpose solution.