# Requirements for Nel Drip Coffee

Tags: pour-over, filter

I have a question about Nel Drip coffee requirements.
Recently I've been checking few blogs and articles about this type of brewing, it mostly leads to these "settings":
- Old coffee beans
- Coarse ground
- Low temperature
- Grounds to water ratio at about 1:4, with the grounds being about 40 to 50 gr

Most of that requirements seems odd to me, it contradict with any other pour over methods, except for the coarse grind setting.

So my question is:
Can anyone explain why it is better to use old coffee beans, low temperature, and 1:4 ratio?

Thanks

Comment: Related: https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/434/how-does-nel-drip-compare-to-paper-filtered-pour-over