# Do Automated Pour Over Machines provide the same flavor profile compared to manual pour over method?

Tags: pour-over

I use 2 manual pourover methods

Method 1: Brown Melitta #4 paper filter rinsed using my Bonavaita drip machine's brew basket. 185F filtered water and beans grinded with Baratza Encore burr grinder

Beans from SquareOne, Intelligentsia, Novo

Method 2: using a Hario V60

Recently I've been noticing several automated pour over machines coming to the market - Poppy Pourover, Bodum, Invergo, Kitchenaid and lots of others getting on the automated pour over bandwagon.

Are these automated pourover machines even worth looking into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several "automatic pour-over" machines have recently come onto the market from manufacturers such as those you listed.  They are something of a hybrid between the ubiquitous, conventional "automatic drip" machines and manual pour-over methods.  That is, the automatic pour-over machines attempt to perform the same sequence of steps recommended for manual pour-over, but in an automated fashion.

For example, compare the [Blue Bottle pour-over drip guide](https://bluebottlecoffee.com/preparation-guides/drip). This suggests a multi-step process of pouring. With water at a particular temperature, do the following:

- heat the cone and wet the filter;
- pour a small amount of water to wet the grounds and "bloom", then wait;
- pour the rest of the water slowly in the middle of the grounds pile.

Some other guides recommend pouring in circular motions, or in multiple iterations, or at a particular rate, or in certain places.  See also the question about [pour-over techniques](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/339/pouring-technique-for-drip-pour-over-coffee).

Regular auto-drip machines, on the other hand, simply drop water in one go over all of the grounds in a somewhat uncontrolled manner.  This also relates to a question: does auto-drip taste different than pour-over? That's a separate, open question.

This article from LifeHacker gives [a comparison between the new-fangled automatic pour-over machines and how they compare to real, manual pour-over](http://lifehacker.com/automatic-pour-overs-do-they-make-a-better-cup-of-coff-1583005950), and another from [HuffPo](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/12/16/ottomatic-chemex-coffee-brewer_n_6329320.html) about the Chemex model. Their conclusions are varied (see article for more) but:

- they're more expensive than conventional drip;
- some models have controllable settings for certain parameters (e.g., bloom time; temperature)
- they provide precise repeatability for certain parameters such as rate, contact time with grounds, water temperature.

Ultimately, they provide attention to detail that can be done by hand; some do this better than others. However, most just heat water and drip it over the grounds somewhat better than a conventional drip coffee maker.

If you...

- don't want to learn the "style" or "art" to manual pour-over, or
- if you appreciate the nuances of manual pour-over (over auto-drip), but can't quite focus attention on details that really distinguish manual pour-over,

these machines might be for you.